# SQL query result from table and WHERE condition from another table

Tags: php, mysql, join

Hello I am using the following query to select data from table properties where some of the columns get the actual data from id from another table. I would like to ask is there a way to make this query to use select the data from the JOINed tables but to use the values from table properties in the WHERE clause ?

```
$query= "SELECT 
   P.id
  ,P.price
  ,P.contract
  ,P.property_type
  ,P.sector
  ,P.title
  ,P.address
  ,P.bedrooms
  ,P.bathrooms
  ,P.price
  ,P.m2
  ,P.text_english
  ,P.photo_01
  ,P.utilities
  ,P.google_maps
  ,P.date


  ,CT.id
  ,CT.english_text
  ,PT.id
  ,PT.english
  ,C.cityname
  ,S.sectorname
  ,S.id
  ,O.ownername
  ,O.phone_one
  ,O.phone_two
  ,O.email
  ,O.notes

FROM properties P
JOIN contract CT
  ON CT.id = P.contract
JOIN property_type PT
  ON PT.id = P.property_type
JOIN city C
  ON C.id = P.city
JOIN sector S
  ON S.id = P.sector
JOIN owner O
  ON O.id = P.owner FROM properties WHERE 1";           
            if (!empty($sector)) { $query .= " P.sector = '$sector'"; }
            if (!empty($property_type))  { $query .= " AND P.property_type = '$property_type'"; }
            if (!empty($contract))  { $query .= " AND P.contract = '$contract'"; }
            if (!empty($minimum_price))  { $query .= " AND P.price BETWEEN '$minimum_price' AND '$maximum_price'"; }
            if (!empty($m2_from))  { $query .= " AND P.m2 BETWEEN '$m2_from' AND '$m2_until'"; }
            if (!empty($bedrooms))  { $query .= " AND P.bedrooms = '$bedrooms'"; }
```

In case if I add more code like:

`,CT.id` and then: `if (!empty($contract))  { $query .= " AND CT.id = '$contract'"; }`

since the id's in the contract are the values in the column contract inside properties it is also not working.

Comment: If you're not too fond of the `JOIN` functions, you could just run two queries, the first to get the `WHERE` value for the second query. I am only suggesting this as I know some people (like me) find using the `JOIN` functions hard. If you don't get what I mean post, I'll try explain.

Comment: I was hoping to add something like: `CT.id` and then `$query .= " S.id = '$sector'";` since the id's are the same but this is giving me error.

Comment: you don't see the code above the if ?

Comment: edited: still need to know what the is error though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think you may need to refresh. You should be able to see a `SELECT` query.

Comment: @Script47 *duh* lol - my bad; been at this too long tonight. Scratch my comments, will delete. But my question to the OP to know what the error is, still stands ;-) Sorry John; tired eyes. I think I'll call it a night. Edit: comments deleted, and one edited.

Comment: Well the problem is that the logic is not working. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Comment: @JohnSiniger does it say where?

Comment: it does: right syntax to use near 'FROM properties WHERE 1 S.id = '2' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 39' in  but this error comes in the pagination class file which is different file.

Comment: @JohnSiniger if that file is causing the error, could you put that code up?

Comment: well that file is 1000 lines. but I think that my SQL syntaxis in the query is not correct.  one of the pagination.php class file where the error comes on it;s line is just: $this->pdos->execute();

Comment: Could you shorten it down to a function? Or some surrounding code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85258/discussion-between-john-siniger-and-script47).